# Android: Action to open up VPN Settings Activity

Tags: android, vpn

I have been looking around for a way to launch the VPN settings activity through my android app, but cannot find it. Note that I am targeting Android 2.2, hence will not be able to use the facilities provided in android ICS.

What is the action that I should pass into an Intent in order to get the VPN settings screen to open up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
    private static final String PACKAGE_PREFIX =
            VpnManager.class.getPackage().getName() + ".";
    private static final String ACTION_VPN_SETTINGS =
            PACKAGE_PREFIX + "SETTINGS";
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_VPN_SETTINGS);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 13):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.net.vpn.SETTINGS");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This works on Kit Kat, thanks.  The VpnManager class shown in the accepted answer appears to have been removed in newer Android OS versions.

Comment: Thanks, android 5.1 is OK, its save my a lot of time everyday ^_-

Comment: Thanks, this worked with "llama" to allow me to send "Start Activity" - the uppercase is what I had been missing.