# Programmatically open a predefined VPN connection on android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, connection, vpn

As the title already says:

Is it possible to connect to/open a VPN connection which has been already set in the settings of the device (native Android VPN settings)?

Is there already any example/source code available?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. A quick search yielded [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731306/android-action-to-open-up-vpn-settings-activity). I know you are new, but try to keep in mind that some research on your part goes a *long way* to helping you out. Did you try anything so far? Please show your efforts first so that other people might help you out. Also, please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @kgdesouz - your link does not address the question of this post, it merely covers how to bring up the settings menu so that a user may *manually* make a selection.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your quick answer. The posted link doesn't answer my question. The question was: "is it possible to establish a predefined vpn connection" not "is it possible to open the vpn settings"...i've already searched threw a whole bunch of questions, faqs, sites and other stuff round the net! but i was not able to find ANYTHING answering my question....sorry for the trouble!!

Comment: nobody hast experience in that case?

Comment: @psicon.psieber Please share your research..