# Action to open up VPN Settings Activity for API > 2.3.7

Tags: android, vpn

I need to open the system vpn settings activity through my app but can't find a way. I noticed there  is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731306/android-action-to-open-up-vpn-settings-activity), but it's asking a solution targeting Android 2.2 which is not applicable for versions above 2.3.7.

So what action should I pass to an Intent to open the system vpn settings activity for android 2.3.7 above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Intent seems to work right now, but it is undocumented and thus not guaranteed to continue to work with future version of Android:

```
startActivity(new Intent("android.net.vpn.SETTINGS"));
```

If you are supporting a minimum SDK version of 14, then you should consider using [`VpnService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html) and the related APIs instead.